# How to change in-line background image depending on screen size?

Tags: jquery, css

Is there anyway to change an in-line background image so if screen size gets down to 767px in width the background URL is changed.

I have the following code at the moment:

```
<section class="inner-header" style="background:url(/images/sports-glasses.jpg) no-repeat center top;">
```

I know that I can set a class or ID to this section and use CSS instead and then use @media queries to change the image but for quickness I would like to know is there a way to change it inline?

Comment: have u looked at the background-size property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a way to change the inline styles, with javascript

```
$(window).on('resize', function() {
    if ( $(this).width < 767 ) {
        $('.inner-header').css('background', 'url(/images/other.jpg) no-repeat center top');
    } else {
        $('.inner-header').css('background', 'url(/images/sports-glasses.jpg) no-repeat center top');
    }
});
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks, this has answered my question.

Comment: not sure why you'd use jquery when a media query would do the same thing?

Comment: @Aaron - because I read the question, specifically where the OP is saying he knows about media queries, but isn't looking for that.

Comment: With media queries, all of the images will be downloaded weather they are used or not. This way only the image that are used will be downloaded

Comment: @Aaron - I'm not sure what the OP means by "quickness", but javascript is never really faster than CSS. I read the question as *"I would like to know is there a way to change it inline"*, and answered that part.

Comment: @uʍopǝpısdn and having jquery fire everytime the browser resizes is better?

Comment: It is if it's bandwidth you are worried about

Comment: @uʍopǝpısdn also, the browser only reads the css it doesn't download the image till the window reaches that size.

Comment: Anyway this guys using inline styles, which in my opinion is unacceptable.

Answer (score 1):

There is a newish answer to responsive inline images using srcset="" which looks like this:

```
<img src="small.jpg"
     srcset="large.jpg 1024w, medium.jpg 640w, small.jpg 320w"
     sizes="(min-width: 36em) 33.3vw, 100vw"
     alt="A rad wolf">
```

see this link for more info http://responsiveimages.org/

Comment: This is *going* to be cool in the future, but it doesn't just swap images on certain pixels, it's intended for images in different resolutions, and the browser calculates which images fits the best, for instance on a retina screen, so you don't really control it, but it's useful if you provide different resolutions of the **same** image.

Comment: <img> is for foreground images, not for background images.

Answer (score 0):

I can't find a way around using CSS in an independant file, but here is my hybrid inline CSS solution:

```css
.inner-header {
  height: 300px;
  background-position: top;
  background-size: cover;
}



.responsive-bg {
      background-image: var(--mobile-bg);
  }

  @media (min-width: 1024px) {
      .responsive-bg {
          background-image: var(--desktop-bg);
      }
  }
```

```html
<section class="inner-header responsive-bg" style="--mobile-bg: url(https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/07/22/15/21/cat-2528935_1280.jpg); --desktop-bg: url(https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/01/19/17/54/dog-1149964_1280.jpg)">
  Lorem ipsum
</section>
```